# Child object doesn't stay relative to parent in BGE

Tags: game-engine, objects, transforms, parent

I'm making (another) plane game but the propeller, which is parented to the plane, keeps moving weirdly.
Here is an image of the whole plane, before I go into the game:
[image: 3dview]

Then, when I go into the game, it looks like this:
[image: game1]

Which is OK, so far. But now, when I move the mouse to rotate the plane, the propeller detaches from the plane:
[image: game3]
[image: game2]

Is there a way to keep the propeller attached in the same position on the plane?

---

If it helps, here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37139).

Comment: use the parent logic brick with always sensor

Comment: @Chebhou This doesn't seem to work - can you explain it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a simple case of unapplied scale and rotation. The odd thing is blender handles parents with different transforms just fine, but the game engine does not.
As a general rule everything in the BGE should have a scale of one, and no rotation.

All I did is apply the scale and rotation on both the plane and the propeller, then the normal object parent worked as expected in the BGE.

**[Here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/363/)** is your fixed blend with parent working, plus you had the normals on your plane reversed.

If you haven't seen my explanation on the parenting settings, go read it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217).

Comment: How do you "apply the scale and rotation"? @David

Comment: @Jacob_ http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6445/2217

Comment: actually never mind, I managed :)

Answer (score 1):

Select two objects, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Rotation & Scale* to apply it to object data.